# Figure generation error

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, data-visualization, bar-chart

[image]

Hi I am getting a figure like this when I try to generate this barchart through Mathematica commandline. I don't get any error but the figure looks weird. Could you please help me figure out why this is happening.

This is the code I am using:

```
bar1to15 = 
  BarChart[Take[FractionsTumor, {1, 15}], ChartStyle -> Red, 
   ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[Thin], 
   FrameTicks -> {Table[i, {i, 1, 15}], Automatic}, 
   Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
   FrameLabel -> {"# Singular Value", "Fraction"}, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "courier", FontSize -> 10}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1];
bar2to15 = 
  BarChart[Take[FractionsTumor, {2, 15}], ChartStyle -> Red, 
   ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[Thin], 
   Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
   FrameTicks -> {{{1, "2"}, {2, "3"}, {3, "4"}, {4, "5"}, {5, 
       "6"}, {6, "7"}, {7, "8"}, {8, "9"}, {9, "10"}, {10, "11"}, {11,
        "12"}, {12, "13"}, {13, "14"}, {14, "15"}}, Automatic}, 
   FrameLabel -> {"# Singular Value", "Fraction"}, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontF amily -> "courier", FontSize -> 10}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1];
bar = GraphicsGrid[{{bar1to15, bar2to15}}, ImageSize -> 500, 
   Spacings -> 10, AspectRatio -> 1, 
   PlotLabel -> "Singular Val Dist - " <> txt];
Export[path <> txt <> "singval.pdf", bar, "PDF", ImageSize -> 500, 
  ImageResolution -> 3600];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typographical error in your code.  This should have been apparent to you from carefully looking at the syntax highlighting.  Compare these two code sections:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can see that after correcting the error the Symbol name `FontFamily` is recognized as a system symbol and styled black.

If you do not have this highlighting enabled you can turn it on from:

`Edit > Preferences...` then `Appearance` and `Syntax Coloring` tabs.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I wouldn't have been able to figure that out ever. I am newbie to both stackoverflow and mathematica. Your solution solved the problem. Should I remove this question as this looks very silly now?

Comment: @user1050325 You're welcome.  If you are learning *Mathematica* be sure to visit http://mathematica.stackexchange.com ; also, read [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18/121).  Don't delete this question; I don't think you'll be able to anyway now that it has an answer with a positive score, and veteran users can vote to "Close" the question if they see fit.  This way the community decides.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the original graphic (`bar`) in Mathematica, you'll see the pink boxes there, as well as the cell bracket being red with a yellow button containing a '+'.  This means that there is an error that occurred when trying to display the result.

If you mouse over the graphic, you get the error displayed as a tooltip.
If you click the yellow button, you get the error displayed in the Messages window.

In this case the message is:

> An improperly formatted option was encountered. The left-hand side of the option was not a symbol or string.

which is vague, but at least suggestive of where to look.